# Unable to download nodejs from kotlin multiplatform gradle project

Tags: node.js, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I have built a kotlin multiplatform project using gradle from my home machine without any problems. However upon entering a corporate proxy that does not allow the downloading of executable files.

I keep getting the following...

```
**Execution failed for task ':kotlinNodeJsSetup'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not resolve org.nodejs:node:14.15.4.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.nodejs:node:14.15.4.
         > Could not get resource 'https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.4/node-v14.15.4-win-x64.zip'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.4/node-v14.15.4-win-x64.zip'.**
```

There must be a way of defining an alternate location of baseUrl to download nodejs from.

I have a location within our company but I want to be able to tell gradle where that location should be.